# Angular 5- How to add multiple parameters to constructor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to add both my service as well as an authentication service to my app.component.ts, but I can't seem to add both in my constructor parameters. How can I do that and still have both available to the whole application?
Here's what I have:

```
constructor(private _dataService: DataService, authToken: Angular2TokenService) {
     this.authToken.init(environment.token_auth_config)
 }
```

The error is: Property 'authToken' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

All necessary items have already been imported.

How can I write both in? Most answers I'm finding are for older versions of Angular. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `private` before `authToken`. Adding `private` makes it a property of the Component class. Then you can refer to the `authToken` with the `this` keyword.

```
constructor(private _dataService: DataService, private authToken: Angular2TokenService) {
     this.authToken.init(environment.token_auth_config)
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used `this` with `authToken` - this means that your `authToken` is declared as property of your component but currently it is not like that so why you get the error.

You need to add `private` or another access modifier before the `authToken`. This tells that the parameter in the constructor is declared as a property of the component like `_dataService`

```
constructor(private _dataService: DataService, private authToken: Angular2TokenService) {
     this.authToken.init(environment.token_auth_config)
}
```